# Change "contour filled" smooth interpolation scheme. And problem with multiple contour filled on same axis

Tags: pgfplots, overleaf, matplotlib

In this post I would like to solve two "issues" concerning PGF.

The first one is the fact that adding multiple `contour filled` on the same axis, is producing a separation line that I would like to remove (see figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E8j0.png)). I am making 3 `contour filled` (hence two separation lines at y~0.8 and y~-0.75) because my data used for plotting is a txt file of ~15000 rows and 3 columns (x, y coordinates and the solution value determining the color). To avoid the famous `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=*****]` error, I split my data into 3 files of ~5000 rows each, and thus making 3 `contour filled` on the same axis, instead of one for the whole data. So my first question is to know how could I remove the separations lines seen in figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E8j0.png) just below, or how I could avoid the memory error.

[image: PGF contour filled]

Now for the second "issue", I would like to plot result of a 2D fluid flow using PGF/TikZ. I tried the `coutour filled` and the `patch` tools (see [PGFplots Manual](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-3dplots), section 17.9: Filled Contour Plots and section 17.13: Patch Plots). In python Matlotlib I have done two things:

1. using `Triangulation` and `LinearTriInterpolator`, I was able to interpolate my solution on a cartesian grid, and then use `contourf` to plot my flow.
2. using my original FEM mesh (triangular elements) and `tricontourf` directly, I got really close result with `contourf`.

The result using Matplotlib is shown below:

[image: Matplotlib contourf]

Now, I would like to produce a similar plot but using the cartesian grid I generated with python, and `contour filled`. The problem is that I am not satisfied with the result.

As stated in PGFplots Manual:

"The results of contour filled always have smooth position interpolation at any resolution."

You can indeed see this on the figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E8j0.png), where I made a `contour filled` (in fact 3 on same axis, as stated before), using the same data as in the Matplotlib `contourf`.

So my question concerning this second "issue" is to know if there where any option to change the smooth position interpolation used in `contour filled`, to make figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E8j0.png) (PGF) look better, and actually look like figure [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv9FP.png) (Matplotlib).

Thanks and regards!